# $a_n=a_{n-1}+3\pmod{n}$ achieves all integer values not $2\pmod3$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Consider a sequence $a_1=0$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}+3\pmod{n}$, with $0\leq a_n\leq n-1$, for $n>1$. Find all positive integers $k$ such that there are infinitely many $n$ for which $a_n=k$.

I think the answer is all $k\not\equiv2\pmod{3}$. Treating $a_n$ as the survivor in the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) for a step of $3$, it's clear that $a_n\not\equiv2\pmod{3}$. To show that $a_n=k$, where $k\not\equiv2\pmod3$, infinitely often, it clearly suffices to show that $a_n$ hits the values of $0$ and $1$ infinitely often. I have established the following relations

$$\begin{align*}a_{2n}=0&\implies a_{3n}=0 \tag1 \\ a_{2n-1}=0&\implies a_{3n-1}=1 \tag2 \\ a_{2n}=1&\implies a_{3n}=1 \tag3 \\ a_{2n+1}=1&\implies a_{3n+1}=0 \tag4\end{align*}$$

but I'm not sure how to complete the proof.

---

**EDIT:** I've solved the problem now. It's clear that $a_n$ hits $0$ **or** $1$ infinitely often. Suppose for contradiction that $a_n=0$ only finitely often. Suppose $a_n\neq0$ for $n>N$ and take $m>N$ with $f(m)=1$. Write $m=2^eq$, with $e\geq0$ and $q$ odd. Applying relation $(3)$ $q$ times gets $a_{3^eq}=1$. Then relation $(4)$ implies that $a_n=0$, where $n=\frac{3^{e+1}q-1}{2}>N$, contradiction.

Similarly, we can show that $a_n=1$ infinitely often, and the problem is solved.

Comment: I took the liberty of numbering your equations so they could be referred to.